# Calculate value per day

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have Oracle table where I insert data about network upload and download speed.

```
CREATE TABLE AGENT_HISTORY(
  EVENT_DATE DATE,
  NETWORK_UP NUMBER,
  NETWORK_DOWN NUMBER
)
```

I want to generate Bar chart for last 30 days and display total upload traffic per day(24 hours).

```
select * from AGENT_HISTORY where EVENT_DATE >= SYSDATE - 30;
```

The problem which I don't know how to solve is how I can calculate the traffic for each day from the column `NETWORK_UP`. The result of the query should be 30 days with total upload traffic for each day. Is this possible without PL/SQL procedure?

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you just want to aggregate the data.  Something like

```
SELECT trunc(event_date), 
       sum(network_up) total_up,
       sum(network_down) total_down
  FROM agent_history
 WHERE event_date >= trunc(sysdate) - 30
 GROUP BY trunc(event_date)
```

If that is not what you want, it would be very helpful to post some sample data, expected output, etc.

Comment: Yes I want to aggregate the data for each day and return it as a result for each day. I run the code but I get Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 14
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @PeterPenzov - Sorry.  I somehow left off the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a query like this to aggregate totals data for both the `network_up` and `network_down` columns per day.

```
select  trunc(event_day,'day') event_date
       ,sum(network_up) tot_network_up
       ,sum(network_down) tot_network_down
from agent_history
where event_day >= trunc(sysdate,'day') - interval '30' day
group by trunc(event_day,'day');
```

You can do it without embbeding the query in PL/SQL stored code depending on what you use for front end, in java you could you use something like this

```
Statement stmt = null;
String schema_name = 'abc';
String query = "select trunc(event_day,'day') event_date," +
               "sum(network_up) tot_network_up," +
               "sum(network_down) tot_network_down " +
               "from " + schema_name +".agent_history " +
               "where event_day >= trunc(sysdate,'day') " +
               "- interval '30' day " +
               "group by trunc(event_day,'day')"
try {
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()) {
        String event_data = rs.getString("EVENT_DATE");
        int tot_network_up = rs.getInt("TOT_NETWORK_UP");
        int tot_network_down= rs.getInt("TOT_NETWORK_DOWN");
      .....
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    .......
} finally {
    ......
}
```

With something like this you just execute pure SQL.